# OroCRM 4.1.20 Install with Vagrant, but website not work (http 500)

Tags: erp, orocrm

I download source and setup (git and vagrant ust be installed)

```
git clone -b 4.1.20 https://github.com/oroinc/orocommerce-application.git oroapp-4.1.20
vagrant up
```

and visit website http://localhost:8000 i get error: http 500

Answer (score 0):

There was an issue with Vagrantfile, that was fixed it in version 4.1.4, Please use [this guide](https://doc.oroinc.com/backend/setup/demo-environment/vagrant/), but change the version to **4.1.4**.

Also, I should note, that this vagrant box intended to be used for demo purposes only. For development we recommend [the local setup](https://doc.oroinc.com/backend/setup/dev-environment/community-edition/).